# how to do a copy of data from one structure pointer to another structure member

Tags: c, pointers, structure, memcpy

I am passing the address of a structure to the function.

```
void validate(void *ptr)
{
    // A variable of type Msgmt Structure
    Msgmt msg;
    memset(&msg, 0, MSG_SIZE);

    // Type casting the void pointer to this structure dev_t
    dev_t *elem = (dev_t*)ptr;
    msg.msg_id = 10;  
    if (elem->devCategory == VAL){  
        // This statement crashes the code
        // memcpy(msg.messageData.value.data, elem->data, LEN);

        // This statement goes through 
        memcpy(&msg.messageData.value.data,elem->data,LEN) ; 
    }

    // ... do something
}
```

messageData is a union within struct msg and value is a member of union and data is an array of unsigned char.

how should I do a memcpy of `elem->data` to the `msg.messageData.value.data` ? (`elem->data` is an array of `unsigned char`)

thanks !!!

Comment: Why are you taking a `void *` if what you really want is a `dev_t *`?

Comment: Can you provide the definitions of the data types you're using? (Source code, not descriptions, please.)

Comment: How is `LEN` defined/calculated?

Answer (score 0):

The statement crashes, because the pointer is NULL.

Here you clear the members.

```
    memset(&msg, 0, MSG_SIZE);

    // Type casting the void pointer to this structure dev_t
    dev_t *elem = (dev_t*)ptr;
```

Here is the only thing that you initiliaze something.

```
    msg.msg_id = 10;  
    if (elem->devCategory == VAL){
```

And here you access the NULL pointer, which luckily for you crashes.

```
        // This statement crashes the code
        // memcpy(msg.messageData.value.data, elem->data, LEN);
```

And here you will corrupt other memory most likely, without crashing.

```
        // This statement goes through 
        memcpy(&msg.messageData.value.data,elem->data,LEN) ; 
    }

    // ... do something
}
```

You must assign `msg.messageData.value.data` some defined memory, before you can use it as a target for `memcp`.

Comment: So you **suppose** `msg.messageData.value.data` to be `char *`, right?

Comment: @alk, what do you mean? The OP overwrites his structure to 0 hence the pointer he is passing to memcp in the commented block means that he is using 0 as the target pointer. Not really surprising that it crashes. In the second statement, he is passing the address of the pointer, and this works of course, because this is on the stack, but it can't be correct, unless LEN == 4. From the incomplete sample he is trying to copy some data structure from elem->data. I assumed that `data` is a pointer because he was using it as target for memcp, but without seeing Msgmt it's hard to say.

Comment: I mean that from the current posting it is unknow whether `msg.messageData.value.data` is declared to be `char *` or something like `char[<somevalue>]`.

Comment: msg - structure, messageData - Union within struct , value - member of union, data - char array[] for that member of union.